# How to export a MySQL database to CSV

Tags: mysql, csv

What is the best way to export a MySQL database to a CSV file without including indexes, table structures etc? 
I just need to get all the data, I have a lot tables so I don't want to do it one by one. 
I'm using 0xdbe and Workbench running on Linux. 
Thanks!

Comment: How do you propose keeping things like indices and table structure in a CSV file though?

Comment: That's the thing I don't want the indices and table structure. I just want the data. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Understood. "Without giving up" something means you want to keep it, this was what caused my confusion.

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mysqldump` has a mode to dump tab-separated files, one per table.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> -T <output_directory> --no-create-info <database_name>
```

With a bit of tweaking this can be make to look like a CSV file.

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> -T <output_directory> --fields-terminated-by ',' --fields-enclosed-by '"' --fields-escaped-by '\' --no-create-info <database_name>
```

Note that the file is written by the database, so whatever user your database is running as needs to have write access to the output directory!

Comment: It worked ok. I got the files on .txt and .sql but I can change them to .csv
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me:

```
 mysqldump DBNAME TABLENAME  --fields-terminated-by ',' \
 --fields-enclosed-by '"' --fields-escaped-by '\' \
 --no-create-info --tab /var/lib/mysql-files/
```

I'm dumping to `/var/lib/mysql-files/` to avoid this error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1290: The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'

Answer (score -4):

mysqldump might be useful in this case. Even though it's not the csv output, it has all the indices and table structures including the data.

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```